# React SetInterval Not Cleaning up

Tags: reactjs

So I have a custom useHook that I want to poll an API. When I perform an action I want the polling to stop. The following code seems to be working fine except if I quickly open and close, when when the fly out closes, it un-renders my react app with this hook but the polling still happens. I tried switching to SWR but the same issues happen

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useFlags } from 'launchdarkly-react-client-sdk';
import {
  IPlannedEvent,
  IWaitlistEntry,
  ReservationItineraryDto,
} from 'typescript-scheduling-types';

import { getClassDetails } from '../actions';
import { logToNewRelic } from '../utils/logger';

export const usePolling = (classId: string): TUsePollingResponse => {
  const flags = useFlags();
  const [classDetailsData, setClassDetailsData] = useState<IPlannedEvent>();
  const [registrantData, setRegistrantData] = useState<ReservationItineraryDto[]>([]);
  const [waitlistData, setWaitlistData] = useState<IWaitlistEntry[]>([]);
  const pollingInterval = useRef<NodeJS.Timeout>();

  useEffect(() => {
    pollingInterval.current = setInterval(() => {
      const classSignInInteraction = window.newrelic ? window.newrelic.interaction() : null;

      if (classSignInInteraction) {
        classSignInInteraction.setName('Sign In Polling');
      }

      getClassDetails(classId, ['WaitlistEntries'])
        .then((data) => {
          if (data.id) {
            setClassDetailsData(data);
          }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          logToNewRelic(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {
          if (classSignInInteraction) {
            classSignInInteraction.end();
          }
        });
    }, flags.classSignInPollingInterval || 60000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(pollingInterval.current as NodeJS.Timeout);
    };
  }, [classId, flags.classSignInPollingInterval]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setRegistrantData(classDetailsData?.reservationItineraryItems || []);
    setWaitlistData(classDetailsData?.waitlistEntries || []);
  }, [classDetailsData]);

  return {
    newClassDetailsData: classDetailsData,
    newRegistrantData: registrantData,
    newWaitlistData: waitlistData,
    pollingInterval: pollingInterval.current,
  };
};

export type TUsePollingResponse = {
  newClassDetailsData: IPlannedEvent | undefined;
  newRegistrantData: ReservationItineraryDto[];
  newWaitlistData: IWaitlistEntry[];
  pollingInterval: NodeJS.Timeout | undefined;
};
```

I tried wrapping in a setTimeout but that suffers the same issue. I got to be missing something here

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging. In addition, I recommend that you install the React Dev Tools addon for your browser and learn how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that you're storing it in a mutable location, and you're probably overwriting the current value before the cleanup logic can run. Instead, just do

```
pollingInterval = setTimeout(()=>{/*...*//}, interval);

return () => clearTimeout(pollingInterval)'
```